# Interference when I use HttpClient

Tags: c#, winforms, console, httpclient

I want to use `HttpClient.GetAsync()`, this is my code in a Console app:

```
public class Program
{
    private static readonly HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();
    static Program()
    {

    }
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await httpclient.GetAsync("http://........"))
            {
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                string responsebody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine(responsebody);
            }
        }
        catch(HttpRequestException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message.ToString());
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

this work complete, but when I use this in a WinForms project, I get an exception on this line:

```
using (HttpResponseMessage response = await httpclient.GetAsync("http://........"))
```

The exception is:

[image]

The code in the WinForms app is:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    private static readonly HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();

    private async void btnSendTest3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await httpclient.GetAsync("http://192.168.1.1/reqproc/proc_get?multi_data=1&isTest=false&cmd=tz_version"))
            {
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                string responsebody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                MessageBox.Show(responsebody);
            }

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

It is interesting that when I run Fiddler before I run my code, my code run correct and complete.
Run code in a Console it works correctly, with or without fiddler but in the  Winforms app, without Fiddler, my code causes an exception.

target framework for console app :
[image]

target framework for winform app :
[image]

Comment: Since you have an issue with your code when it's run in a WinForms Project, why did you post the (working) Console version? Post the (whole) implementation that generates the problem -- What is the `static Program()` thing there?

Comment: @Jimi I have sent the console code to show that the code works correctly.
The program class is nothing, I have to delete it.

Comment: @Jimi update my question. . plz help

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code, the exception is cause by the endpoint's response. Could be a Proxy issue, since you mentioned Fiddler, though the Server is in a local area network. Is it the same Server also in the Console app? Did you code the response? What .Net version are you targeting in both applications?

Comment: @Jimi yes url is my modem ip (192.168.1.1). both of url server is same (console app and winform app). target framework for console app is .net 6  and  for winform is .net framework 4.7

Comment: @Jimi yes my code on console app response correctly.

Comment: So, the endpoint is actually the Web service of a router? -- The HttpClient implementation in .Net Framework and .Net is quite different and you're targeting .Net Framework 4.7 in WinForms. Not good. Build a .Net 6 WinForms Project and try again (but, since you're there, test .Net Framework 4.8 first).

Comment: @Jimi yes that is actually web service of a router.  i check with other .net framework version but not work too.

Comment: @jimi i test with .net6 winform my code work without exception . how can i convert my project to .net 6?

Comment: That depends on the complexity of the .Net Framework Project. You may have no issues  at all or some or many. See: [Overview of porting from .NET Framework to .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/) and [Overview of the .NET Upgrade Assistant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/upgrade-assistant-overview) -- If you're using third-party packages, Custom Controls etc., you have to verify that there's a .Net version available -- Have you tested .Net Framework 4.8?

Comment: @Jimi yes .not work on .net framework 4.8 and other version

Comment: Well, it was worth trying. Good luck :)

Comment: @Jimi tnx alot. u are best. tnxxxxx

Comment: Have you tried adding httpclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Anything")?

Comment: @MDZand yes but is not work